# What happens to Klingons who die on Starfleet ships?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

In the TNG episode Heart of Glory, Worf states that once a Klingon has died their body becomes an empty shell, and should be treated as such.

What exactly does this mean for the crew? Organic waste can be recycled into the replicator system or ejected from an airlock, but would they feel comfortable doing that? Would they respect Klingon tradition, and if so what does that entail?